# Translate C program to other programming languages

Tags: c

I am trying to translate a C program. The destination language doesn't really matter, I am just trying to understand what every single part of the program is doing.

I cannot find any detail about:

```
variable=1;
while(variable);
```

I understand that this is a loop and that is true (I have read similar questions on stack overflow where a code was actually executed) but in this case there is no code related to this while. So I am wondering, is the program "sleeping" - while this while is executing?

Then, another part I don't understand is:

```
variable=0;
variable=variable^0x800000;
```

I believe that value should be 24bits but is this really needed in any other programming language that is not low level as C?

Many thanks

Comment: The loop is an infinite loop that does nothing but occupy CPU cycles. Most importantly it *doesn't* put the process to sleep, it's a busy-wait loop that will use as much CPU time as it can. As for the other thing, it depends. You really can't do any kind of translation unless you know both the source and target language, and you need to know them well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you. I cannot really believe that is "useless". This is written in the documentation of a popular hardware chip :-/ Why would they use that if the only purpose is to use cpu...

Comment: if the variable is volatile, and some kind of interrupt set the variable = 0, the loop can exit... ;)

Comment: Maybe its purpose is to just do nothing while there are other processes doing work? I.e. it's a kind of idle process?

Comment: In C, variables have a type. so `variable = 0` requires more initial information, such as a declaration (`int variable`). this information and the assignment can be unified. i.e. `uint32_t variable - 0` (this is a 32bit type, while `int` is architecture dependent and has no specific but length).

Comment: @LPs, that's what I was thinking, but if the rest of the program is not "sleeping" during this while, so what is the use of it

Comment: @MeV such loops can be used in place of a Mutex, allowing critical sections to be protected in multi-threaded programs.

Comment: This should really be two different questions.

Comment: It really deopends on the whole code. Is that while into a low priority task? Is there a kind of interrupt that managed the variable? Is there a parallel task that manage the variable? ans so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(variable);` implements a *spin-lock*; i.e. this thread will remain at this statement until `variable` is 0. I've introduced the term to help you search for a good technique in your new language.

It obviously burns the CPU, but can be quite an efficient way of doing this if only used for a few clock cycles. For it to work well, `variable` needs to be qualified with `volatile`.

`variable = variable ^ 0x800000;` is an XOR operation, actually a single bit toggle in this case. (I would have preferred to see `variable ^= 0x800000` in multi-threaded code.)  Its exact use is probably explainable from its context. Note that the arguments of the XOR are promoted to `int` if they are smaller than that. It's doubtful that `variable^0x800000` is a 24 bit type *unless* `int` is that size on your platform (unlikely but possible).

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to translate a C program.

**Don't translate a *C* program**, unless you are writing a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (sometimes called a transpiler - or [source to source compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) -, if translating to some other programming language different of assembler) which would do such task. And you'll need a lot of work (at least several months for a naive compiler à la [TinyCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler), and more probably many dozens of years)

**Think in *C*** and try to understand its [*semantics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) (much more important than its *syntax*).

> `while(variable);`

that loop has an empty body. It is more readable to make that empty body apparent (semantics remain the same):

```
 while(variable) {};
```

Since the body (and the test) of the loop don't change `variable` (it has no *observable* [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)) the loop will run indefinitely as soon as the initial value of `variable` is non-zero. This will heat your processor.

But you might have declared that `variable` as [*volatile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_%28computer_programming%29) and then have something external changing it.

> `variable=variable^0x800000;`

The `^` is a [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR). You are toggling (replacing 0 with 1 and 1 with 0) a single bit (the 23<sup>rd</sup> one, IIRC)

Comment: Nicked your "toggle" comment. Now upvoting this to try to clear my conscience.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: 
variable=0;
variable=variable^0x800000;

This operation is a bitwise operation called XOR. 
An XOR operation is usually used to toggle bits regardless of it's previous state:

`0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0`